# Create multiple rewrite endpoints for custom taxonomy archive

Tags: custom-taxonomy, rewrite-rules, endpoints

I am trying to create custom end point for the custom taxonomy - 'species'

I am trying to use urls like

```
https://example.com/dogs/shop/
https://example.com/cats/shop/

https://example.com/dogs/services/
https://example.com/cats/services/

https://example.com/dogs/sales
https://example.com/cats/sales
```

where dogs, cats is taxonomy term

Following is the code

```
function my_register_my_taxes_species() {

    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'shop', EP_PAGES );

    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'services', EP_PAGES );

    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'sales', EP_PAGES );

    add_filter('request', function($vars) {
        if (isset($vars['shop'])) {
            $vars['shop'] = true;
        }
        if (isset($vars['services'])) {
            $vars['services'] = true;
        }

        if (isset($vars['sales'])) {
            $vars['sales'] = true;
        }          
        return $vars;
    });

    add_filter('template_include', function($template) {
        if (is_tax('species') && get_query_var('shop')) {
            $post = get_queried_object();
            $end_template = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'templates/shop.php';
            return $end_template;
        }
        if (is_tax('species') && get_query_var('services')) {
            $post = get_queried_object();
            $end_template = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'templates/services.php';
            return $end_template;
        }
        if (is_tax('species') && get_query_var('sales')) {
            $post = get_queried_object();
            $end_template = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'templates/sales.php';
            return $end_template;
        }
        return $template;
    });
    
    $args = [
        "label" => __( "Species", "hello-elementor-child" ),
        "public" => true,
        "publicly_queryable" => true,
        "hierarchical" => true,
        "rewrite" => [ 'slug' => 'species', 'with_front' => true,'ep_mask'=> EP_PAGES, 'hierarchical' => true ],
    ];
    register_taxonomy( "species", [ "job_listing", "product" ], $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'my_register_my_taxes_species' );
```

**This code above works fine upto one endpoint but not working for multiple endpoints like following**

```
https://example.com/dogs/shop/prod-cat1
https://example.com/dogs/shop/prod-cat2
https://example.com/cats/shop/prod-cat1
https://example.com/cats/shop/prod-cat2
```

**Uses template  shop-cat.php & value of query variable i.e prod-cat1, prod-cat2  available on template**

```
https://example.com/dogs/services/sr1
https://example.com/dogs/services/sr2 
https://example.com/cats/services/sr3
https://example.com/cats/services/sr4
```

**Uses template  services-cat.php & value of query variable i.e sr1, sr2  available on template**

```
https://example.com/dogs/sales/sl1
https://example.com/dogs/sales/sl2
https://example.com/cats/sales/sl3
https://example.com/cats/sales/sl4
```

**uses template  sales-cat.php & value of query variable i.e sl1, sl2  available on template**

How can I create multiple endpoints and the assign templates and use the query variables

Comment: Sounds like you are using WooCommerce in this mix?

Comment: Yes Mark it is Woocommerce + wp job manager

Comment: @SallyCJ  I have been looking around and I found multiple answers by you related to this topic.. Will you please able to help me on this please

Comment: I swear we get this question every week

Comment: @user7459842 Are you sure the path is like `/dogs/shop/` and not `/species/dogs/shop/` (note the `/species`)? Or did you mean you have a Page (post type `page`) with the slug `dogs`? And I did notice 1 issue in your code, but, "not working for multiple endpoints" - what/how exactly are they not working? The page uses the default template and not your custom template file? And BTW, just a note that I wasn't notified when you tagged me in your previous comment - maybe because I had never commented before..

Comment: @SallyCJ

Yes you are right.

Archive for this custom taxonomy was - /species/dogs but i wanted them like /dogs i.e without taxonomy slug.So I used a plugin to get rid of that.

So to answer your question-  Yes i need it like this

/dogs/shop/
/dogs/services/
/dogs/sales/

till this where there is just one endpoint the code works

but I need to be able to get the query variable of second end point 

/prod-cat1  in https://example.com/dogs/shop/prod-cat1
/sr1        in  https://example.com/dogs/services/sr1

and assign templates accordingly

Answer (score 2):

> **This code above works fine up to one endpoint but not working for multiple endpoints like following**
>
> ```
> https://example.com/dogs/shop/prod-cat1
> https://example.com/dogs/shop/prod-cat2
> https://example.com/cats/shop/prod-cat1
> https://example.com/cats/shop/prod-cat2
> ```
>
> **Uses template shop-cat.php & value of query variable i.e prod-cat1, prod-cat2 available on template**

Your `request` hook callback is always setting the query var to `true`, like so (for the `shop` var):

```php
if (isset($vars['shop'])) {
    $vars['shop'] = true;
}
```

So instead of doing that, you can use this which sets the var to `true` **only if it is empty**(-ish):

```php
if (isset($vars['shop']) && ! $vars['shop']) {
    $vars['shop'] = true;
}
```

So with that, at `example.com/dogs/shop/`, `get_query_var( 'shop' )` would return `true`, whereas at `example.com/dogs/shop/prod-cat1`, you'd get `prod-cat1`.

And then now you could just use your own conditional to load different templates based on the query var value.

For example, in your `template_include` hook callback, replace the `$end_template = ...;` part with:

```php
$filename = ( true === get_query_var( 'shop' ) ) ?
    // shop-cat.php is used if a custom value like prod-cat1 is set (in the URL)
    'shop.php' : 'shop-cat.php';

$end_template = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . "templates/$filename";
```

Just copy that and the above `if` for the other vars (`sales` and `services`), and replace `shop` with the correct var.

#### Alternate solution without having to modify the query var *value*.

1. Remove the `add_filter('request', function($vars) { ... });` from your code.
2. Replace your entire `template_include` code with:

   ```php
   add_filter( 'template_include', function ( $template ) {
       // Do nothing if we're not on a 'species' taxonomy/term archive page.
       if ( ! is_tax( 'species' ) ) {
           return $template;
       }

       // I used a `foreach` instead of 3 "if" blocks with identical code.
       foreach ( array( 'shop', 'sales', 'services' ) as $var ) {
           if ( isset( $GLOBALS['wp']->query_vars[ $var ] ) ) {
               // <var>-cat.php is used if a custom value like prod-cat1 is set (in the URL)
               $filename = get_query_var( $var ) ? "$var-cat.php" : "$var.php";

               return plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . "templates/$filename";
           }
       }

       return $template;
   } );
   ```

So in the above code, if `$GLOBALS['wp']->query_vars[ $var ]` is set, then we change the template.

Comment: thanks a lot .. I will implement this code and get back to you if any issues

Comment: So did it work?

Comment: Hey I am really sorry for the delayed response.. 
I tried it just now...  
it works well 
but it created issue on single post type .. 
for eg: for a single post with url like 


https://example.com/dogs/services/parent-service-1/child-parent-2/my-post-name 

This is supposed to use single-job_listing.php template but is using taxonomy-species.php

Comment: If it works well, then I'd appreciate an upvote from you? And I don't know which "it"/code you've tried or are using now, but as for the **(single) CPT** permalink issue and with the 2nd snippet in my answer, try adding `if ( false !== strpos( get_query_var( $var ), '/' ) ) { return $template; }` right below the `foreach ( array( 'shop', 'sales', 'services' ) as $var ) {`.

Comment: Ofcouse. I was doing it to accept is as answerayways because it answers my question .. It is problem of my complex permalink struture.. SO I have voted it up and accepted answer but I hope you will help me get the fix

Comment: Nope its is not working . still same issue . :(

Comment: My apologies, I've been quite occupied lately, hence I was unable to reply earlier. And sorry that the snippet in my previous comment didn't work. But then, is that the reason you unaccepted my answer after stating my answer answered your question? And actually, if the plugin is unable to help you achieve the complex permalink structure, then you could try another plugin, or post another question and ask how to achieve the structure without using a 3rd-party plugin? Yes, it wouldn't be easy to remove the `species` base, but it's not impossible, either.

Comment: Hey @SallyCJ . I totally understand . since I as not able to tag you in comment , I thought you may have not got notification of my message. More over I think even if I have 'species' as base slug, even then this problem stays as it that is single post  for the post type stops working. Since this is creating other problem, so I think this code needs inprovement. So I was hoping for an answer if you have time OR may be some one else may stumble on to this question if they see it answers. SO I am sorry if you feel marking it answered was wrong

Comment: Alright then, maybe somebody would come up with a better answer. But my answer was really just telling you that if you want to be able to get the different/correct query var value (e.g. `prod-cat1`), then don't set the value to be always true like your original code was doing. So if something went wrong after implementing my suggestion, then maybe you didn't implement it correctly or that the problem already existed before, but you just didn't realize it.